# How to set CUDA floating-point rounding mode for atomics?

Tags: floating-point, cuda, atomic

CUDA's handling of floating-point rounding modes is discussed [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html). While various intrinsics such as `__fadd_rn` are available for performing rounded operations within the normal flow of the program (adding with round-to-nearest here), the rounding mode of atomics such as [`atomicAdd`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#atomicadd) don't seem to be specified and a method for setting this rounding mode isn't discussed.

Is it possible to set the rounding mode of CUDA atomics?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Quoting from the PTX instruction set [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-atom):

> The floating-point operation `.add` operation rounds to nearest even.
> Current implementation of `atom.add.f32` on global memory flushes
> subnormal inputs and results to sign-preserving zero; whereas
> atom.add.f32 on shared memory supports subnormal inputs and results
> and doesn't flush them to zero.
>
> `atom.add.f16` and `atom.add.f16x2` operation requires the `.noftz`
> qualifier; it preserves subnormal inputs and results, and does not
> flush them to zero.

Another way to think of it: The limited atomic floating support available in current CUDA hardware is done by an ALU in the memory controller, not by the floating point hardware in the SMs. The latter has all the rounding modes implemented, the former doesn't.